# How to hide drawn values in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I need to hide the value above bars in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for barchart. I have tried all the methods available in it , but could not find the solution.

Comment: Is there any method to hide the visibility of whole BAR ? Visibility GONE or INVISIBLE ?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try `dataSet.setDrawValues(false)`. This will **prevent any values from being drawn**.

In case you want to alter (customise) the drawn values (or only individual values), you can use the [ValueFormatter](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/formatting-data-values/) interface and implement your own logic (e.g. hide specific values based on a condition). Always keep in mind performance is critical when using the `ValueFormatter`.

Comment: Hi Philipp,

I have a stackBar Chart. I want to display one value on top of the bar chart and not for each stack of the bar. Can this be done using MpAndroidchart library?

Comment: can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230343/how-to-remove-lines-if-values-is-0-in-pie-chart

Comment: I too need help with ^ @gaurang's question. please help.

Comment: How can I add toggle values to lineChart? `dataSet.setDrawValues(false)`  hides the values. I need to tap on every circle and showing a custom view(the value and date). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there any method to hide the visibility of whole BAR ? Visibility GONE or INVISIBLE ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide values by condition, you can use a Formatter. Here is an example:

You have to call this method:

```
dataSet.setDrawValues(true)
```

and your have add a condition to your formatter:

```
public class MyYAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyYAxisValueFormatter() {

        // format values to 1 decimal digit
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0");
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        String val = ""
        if ((int)value > 10){
            val = value
        }
        return mFormat.format(val);
    }

    /** this is only needed if numbers are returned, else return 0 */
    /*@Override
    public int getDecimalDigits() { return 1; }*/
}
```

If you want to hide all of the values you can use this:

```
dataSet.setDrawValues(false)
```

Comment: Is there any method to hide the visibility of whole BAR ? Visibility GONE or INVISIBLE ?