# how to remove lines if values is 0 % in pie chart

Tags: android, charts, pie-chart, mpandroidchart, overlapping

I'm working on a pie chart, for that, i'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library, the values may contain 0% for any data or more than one data and I'm displaying values outside of piechart using `setYValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE)`.
I don't want to display 0% values in a pie chart, I got a solution for that to use value formatted.

```
public class CustomPercentFormatter implements IValueFormatter {    

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public CustomPercentFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0");
    }

    public CustomPercentFormatter(DecimalFormat format) {
        this.mFormat = format;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {

        if (value == 0.0f)
            return "";

        return mFormat.format(value) + " %";
    }
}
```

But if I'm using lines option then the line is displayed for 0 % values and overlapping for multiple 0% values, so can anyone help me to **remove line option for 0% values**?

[image]

Comment: I too am stuck with it, https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/pull/1703/commits/518bd0e096fa12251bb82754ff708214f4e4d9d4 this says issue is closed. But, I am not able to find method pieChart.setDrawEmptyXLabel(false); using MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'

Comment: have to change PieChartRenderer.java method drawValues()
if (entry.getValue() != 0.0) {
                        if (dataSet.getValueLineColor() != ColorTemplate.COLOR_NONE) {
                            c.drawLine(pt0x, pt0y, pt1x, pt1y, mValueLinePaint);
                            c.drawLine(pt1x, pt1y, pt2x, pt2y, mValueLinePaint);
                        }
                    }

Comment: Hi can you please tell me how ur placing the text outside of the graph ?

Comment: you can set data through https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the method **`drawValues`** in **`PieChartRenderer`** class.

Do not display line if value is 0.

Just put one condition:

```
if (entry.getValue() != 0.0) {
    if (dataSet.getValueLineColor() != ColorTemplate.COLOR_NONE) {
        c.drawLine(pt0x, pt0y, pt1x, pt1y, mValueLinePaint);
        c.drawLine(pt1x, pt1y, pt2x, pt2y, mValueLinePaint);
    }
}
```

Instead of following code:

```
if (dataSet.getValueLineColor() != ColorTemplate.COLOR_NONE) {
    c.drawLine(pt0x, pt0y, pt1x, pt1y, mValueLinePaint);
    c.drawLine(pt1x, pt1y, pt2x, pt2y, mValueLinePaint);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want those lines to get drawn, you have to set the color of that line to `ColorTemplate.COLOR_NONE`.

I don't have enough of your original code to point out what exactly to do, but on the example https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java#L199 you can check how to do it.

Comment: you can not directly change color by writing code for the line, its fix black color from that library.

Comment: @gaurang check the example https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java#L199

Comment: you can use setValueLineColor(), but only once, if you are going to use it as ColorTemplate.COLOR_NONE then no where you can see the lines, and look at the question i have asked that dont want to show lines where value is zero.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but your "solution" isn't good, you are saying that you will change a library ( or open a merge request of changes) that you will no longer get updates.

Comment: But its doing what i want.

Comment: ok open merge request to that library, to use custom library for you without updates will not be a good solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155241/discussion-between-gaurang-and-gmetax).