# Hide small values in a pie chart MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, android-studio, charts, mpandroidchart

How can I hide small values in a PieChart if I am printing them outside the graph? I can get the label to be empty with a ValueFormatter but I can't understand how I would delete the line going outside the graph.

This is my current situation (without the Value Formatter to hide small values): [current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4KGl.png)

Answer (score 0):

this link may be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46403088/5482918

need to change the method `drawValues` in `PieChartRenderer` class

While adding data:

```
 ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new PieEntry(75,"Data 1","showLine"));
    entries.add(new PieEntry(25,"Data 2","hideLine"));
    entries.add(new PieEntry(45,"Data 3","hideLine"));
    entries.add(new PieEntry(58,"Data 4","showLine"));
    entries.add(new PieEntry(76,"Data 5","hideLine"));
```

`PieChartRenderer` class - `drawValues(Canvas c)` method: put condition like:

```
if (entry.getData().equals("showLine")) {
                    if (dataSet.getValueLineColor() != ColorTemplate.COLOR_NONE) {
                        if (dataSet.isUsingSliceColorAsValueLineColor()) {
                            mValueLinePaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j));
                        }
                        c.drawLine(pt0x, pt0y, pt1x, pt1y, mValueLinePaint);
                        c.drawLine(pt1x, pt1y, pt2x, pt2y, mValueLinePaint);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Yes this could be an idea but i would need to determine dynamically what values to hide, so I can't put a fixed number like that.

Comment: no need to give fixed value. You can pass a extra param while adding PieEntry, like:
`entries.add(new PieEntry(5,"Data Small","false"));
entries.add(new PieEntry(105,"Data Big","true"));` 

And in PieChartRenderer class, you can add condition like:
`if (entry.getData().equals("true")) {`

Comment: This should work, gonna test it tomorrow and report back here! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try **dataSet.setDrawValues(false)**. This will prevent any values from being drawn.

In case you want to alter (customise) the drawn values (or only individual values), you can use the ValueFormatter interface and implement your own logic (e.g. hide specific values based on a condition). Always keep in mind performance is critical when using the ValueFormatter.

Comment: I already tried using ValueFormatter and it works but it doesn't remove the arrow.